# image change every a fixed time in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have 4 images. I want to load image in first screen and change images after every 10 second. when we click any images than next screen come up.

please give me help i am new in iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NSTimer to trigger the image change. If the user taps an image and you want to stop the image rotation, you can invalidate the timer before switching to the next view.

Comment: There's a full explanation with examples in the [Timer Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/) document.

Answer (score 1):

You can try by creating a method that changes the image in the imageView and calling it using a `NSTimer` which repeatedly calls the method every 10 seconds.

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0  target:self selector:@selector(changeImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)changeImage {

// Change image here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

HI Avinash,

I think you need below code...

*********** IN VIEW DID LOAD

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0  target:self selector:@selector(changeImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];



- (void)changeImage {

[self.imgview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]];

}
```

Thx

Comment: declare a variable in changeimage and change its value according to it. and change the image.

Comment: i can't understand what u say.

Comment: Please clear your basic concept about objective c. then start working on this.